# Can't get AWS SDK for PHP Working on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, suhosin

I have been trying to get the AWS SDK Installed and working on my EC2 instance. I am running Ubuntu server and have tried requiring the `aws.phar` file in my code and also installing via PEAR. either way I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'S3BrowserUpload' not found in /var/www/...
```

The fact that there's no error from requiring the SDK made me think its a problem with suhosin configuration as stated on the install page. The problem is, I do not have a suhosin.ini file anywhere on the server.

If I run `php -v` it shows me that I do indeed have suhosin though:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

In the absence of the suhosin.ini file I tried adding:

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```

to `php.ini` and restarting apache. No dice.
I installed composer but have not configured it yet because I don't really want to go through all the hassle of setting that up just to run into the same (suhosin?) issue.

**Problem resolved. that class isn't in the latest version of the SDK** :( 
smh...